# VB - Reference Control via a string stored in My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, controls

I'm making an extremely simple app which has multiple screens (as Panels) that are hidden/shown clicking buttons on a left sidebar.

I have a PNLHome, PNLServerSettings, PNLScripts, and PNLSettings as the main panels.
Each of the Panels .Name properties are "PNLHome", "PNLServerSettings", ....etc.

I want to be able to change the "Start Up Screen" based on the selection you make in a ComboBox in PNLSettings, so when you launch the app, the Panel that is immediately showing is based on that ComboBox selection.

I have the ComboBox items in place and I have a function that hides all panels and shows the one you pass into it:
showPanel(PNLHome) for example which will essentially just show the Panel you give it, all this is working fine. This showPanel() is triggered upon clicking one of the main buttons on the left sidebar

What I want is to pass a Control.Name string into my showPanel() func, then I want to store this .Name string into My.Settings via a "Save/Apply" button in the Settings Panel which I can set up easily.

Since I will be passing the .Name String into my showPanel() function, I need to be able to reference the Panel I'm showing by it's name rather than the Object ID itself (I'm not sure if it's called an ID but it's the 'name' declaring the Panel via a "DIM WithEvents PNLHome As Panel" declaration.

To summarize the question; Can I reference the PNLHome by its .Name Property?
Otherwise can I store the ID of PNLHome directly in My.Settings instead? I could easily pass My.Settings.StartPanel into my showPanel() func.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Controls collection to find the control.

```
Private Function GetPanel(PanelName As String) As Panel
    Dim SomePanel As Panel = CType(Controls(PanelName), Panel)
    Return SomePanel
End Function
```